# How can I write multiple XML files using one sketch

Tags: java, xml, processing

Does anybody have some advice on how I can write multiple XML files with only the code of one sketch. I'm trying to do this using the ProXML library but that doesn't work. For some reason, one of the two XML files is 'polluted' with data that should only be in the other file.

Thanks

Comment: "sketch" is not defined in java.  What do you mean by "code of one sketch"?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is to use the printwriter, and writing XMLElement.toString() for the content of your files:

```
XMLElement xmle1 = ...;
PrintWriter output = createWriter("file_1.xml"); 
output.println(xmle1.toString());
output.flush(); // always flush before closing, just to be sure
output.close();

XMLElement xmle2 = ...;
output = createWriter("file_2.xml"); 
output.println(xmle2.toString());
output.flush();
output.close();
```

This does not generate xml files with a doctype, but they're certainly Processing-compatible in that the written XML can be read back in to form an equivalent XMLElement.

(reference page for PrintWriter: http://processing.org/reference/PrintWriter.html)